# Slick.js : Scroll through carousel items without selecting slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, carousel, slick.js

I am using slick carousel in one of my projects & have added the configuration to display the next and prev button.

I am trying to tweak the default behavior of the next and prev button in such a way that clicking them just scrolls from left to right but the currently selected slide will remain the same. I am not able to tweak this default behavior and clicking the next and prev button is changing the selected slide as well. Has anyone tried the same?

```
$('.product-slider').slick({
                dots: true,
                infinite: false,
                speed: 700,
                slidesToShow: 4,
                slidesToScroll: 4,
                responsive: [{
                        breakpoint: 1024,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 3,
                            slidesToScroll: 3,
                            infinite: false,
                            dots: true
                        }
                    }, {
                        breakpoint: 768,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 2,
                            slidesToScroll: 2,
                            infinite: false,
                            dots: true
                        }
                    }, {
                        breakpoint: 480,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 1,
                            slidesToScroll: 1,
                            infinite: false,
                            dots: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
```

Comment: Share you code with us